# getting a substring from a text file for later use

Tags: parsing, ant

I have a text file that contains version information.  There are multiple lines, but the specific line i need looks like this:

```
#define SW_VERSION "3.4.3.1 R3    08-06-12"
```

I specifically need the 3.4.3.1 R3 from the text file.

My first thought was to do execute a short script that would grab this data out and use a set for later use, though i am having quite a bit of trouble getting it to work.

I ran this: `Find /I "#define SW_VERSION" C:\SW\bin\SW_Version.txt` 
and it showed me the line in the file that i expected, but i couldn't figure out how to parse it afterwards.  Help?

Comment: Windows command line is very bad for parsing

Comment: I have 2 options, do it in the middle of a script that is already running, or find out that information as part of an ant build.  Other than that, i find your comment pretty useless.

Comment: then tag it properly. What type of script are you running for option 1?

Comment: it's not specified, so i assume it is a simple batch file.

Comment: The ultimate solution i am going for is to get that version and append that to the name of my jar, i.e: myJar-3.4.3.1R3.jar.  I can either do that while executing the ant build script, or get it while i'm executing the windows batch file and do a rename of the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [custom task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) for Ant.

Your custom task would parse the version line and extract the information you need.